# setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) causes app to crash

Tags: android, xml, crash, setcontentview

Making a calculator program for android and I have an xml file that has all the buttons nesesary to write the program. It shows up in the design part of android studio, but when I'm trying to run my app on an android phone (not emulator; it runs too slow on my pc) it just causes it to crash. Not sure why either.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="7"
        tools:context="com.example.pvtboromeo.calc.MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="4"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingBottom="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNegative"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPercent"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="%"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border2"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border2"
            android:text="X"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFive"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSix"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border2"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border2"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonZero"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border2"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </GridLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is my java file

```
package com.example.pvtboromeo.calc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Without the setContentView code, my app runs but nothing is displayed (obviously) but now my app crashes when I try to run it. The error just says 'Unfortunatly, Calc+ has stopped.'

I'm new to android development. Am I missing something? All my syntax seems to be good.

**Note:** I also checked if android.R was imported instead of my package R, but it's not there...

**Edit:** So I've just messed around with a test project and found out that it's the GridLayout that's causing the app to crash. I'm running using android 5.1.1 (Lolipop) not sure if that helps or not. I believe it's api 22. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the stack trace.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by removing the <layout></layout> tags at the beginning and ending.

Answer (score 0):

1) configure your app to use data binding:

go to build.gradle (Module:app) and insert:

```
android {
    ....
     dataBinding { //line to insert
     enabled = true  //line to insert
}
```

}

1.1) synk your project.

2) insert in your layout tag:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Your xml code will start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <GridLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="7"
        tools:context="com.example.pvtboromeo.calc.MainActivity">
```

3) rebuild your project

4) run your project.

If you want more info about data binding look this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Good luck!

This is my code:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_app_id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Remember to rebuild the project before to use ActivityMainBinding.

Comment: I tried using data binding but always got an error saying could not find resours ActivityMainBinding or something lol. So I gave up on binding lol

Comment: Have you rebuild your project before to use ActivityMainBinding class in your MainActivity?? Now I'll post my code, so you can try to use that.